# bootstrap-select does not proxies click event

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, select, onclick

I had select element:

```
  <select id='selectBox'>
    <option>Mustard</option>
    <option>Ketchup</option>
    <option>Relish</option>
  </select>
```

and set click event via jquery:

```
$('#selectBox option').click(function(){
.....
});
```

after using http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/ :

```
  <select id='selectBox' class="selectpicker" multiple="" data-selected-text-format="count">
    <option>Mustard</option>
    <option>Ketchup</option>
    <option>Relish</option>
  </select>
```

I got nice multiply dropdown and all work fine except that when I click on menu item (select or delestct it) nothing happends.

Why not click event proxies from my original (which was hided) option element to the new created element 'ul.dropdown-menu li a' ? How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried `$('#selectBox option').on('click', function(){});`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change you code to:

```
$('#selectBox').on('change', function(){
    .....
});
```

this must work;

Comment: Yes, this work. Thanks. It is not exactly what I need, but it gives me nessasary functionaluty.

Comment: This isn't an answer, it's a workaround.  There are legitimate use cases for _needing_ the click event.

Answer (score 0):

While `$("#selectBox").change(...)` / `.on("change", ...)` fire when the dropdown menu option changes, it will not work when the selection stays the same.

If you want to e.g. check a radio button associated with the dropdown menu as soon as the dropdown closes, use the `hidden.bs.select` event.

We could also use the related `show.bs.select` or `shown.bs.select` as long as we do not cause the dropdown to lose focus and close.

The drawback is that we get the event even if we do not change the dropdown menu selection, e.g. by opening and then clicking outside the dropdown without selecting an option.

See [bootstrap-select documentation on events](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/options/#events).