# Bootstrap-select clear when chosen empty option

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

I'm using [bootstrap-select](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select) like this:

```html
<select name="country_key" class="show-menu-arrow" multiple
        data-container="body" data-width="250px" >
    <option value="">-clear-</option>
    <option value="1">USA</option>
    <option value="2">Russia</option>
    <option value="3">China</option>
    <option value="4">Spain</option>
</select>
```

I can select `multiple` options, but I also need to clear which options I chosen.

For example, if I choose `USA` and `Spain`, when I click `-clear-`, I need to clear the other options and close the dropdown.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: What have you tried? Bootstrap-select component does have some method, including 'deselect all', you just need to add an onclick listener I guess. Why would you want this implemented that way though? A separate clearing control would be a much better choice.

Comment: Please write me code, I didn't know how can do it. I need this functions, because if users choose 2-3 option, maybe they want's to deselect, and when click to empty option, he select to... This empty option I need to.

Answer (score 1):

You can programmatically clear the selected options by calling [`.selectpicker('deselectAll')`](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/#selectAll).

You'll also need to tap into the change event for the select box to see if you need to call into the method.  To do that, just [monitor the `change` event on the original select element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18660822/1366033).

```js
$('#country_key').on('change', function(){
  if (this[0].selected) {
    $(this).selectpicker('deselectAll');
  }
});
```

#### Demo in Stack Snippets

```js
$('#country_key').on('change', function(){
  if (this[0].selected) {
    $(this).selectpicker('deselectAll');
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/css/bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>

<select id="country_key" data-container="body" 
        class="selectpicker show-menu-arrow" data-width="250px" multiple>
    <option value="" >-clear-</option>
    <option value="1">USA</option>
    <option value="2">Russia</option>
    <option value="3">China</option>
    <option value="4">Spane</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Nice thx. But at my page is didn't want to work, Chrome console, can't see error. hmm.

Comment: I'm using the id selector to grab `#country_key` so you should add that to your page.  If it's working for you in the snippet.  Just start copying over the demo line by line to see where it breaks. We can't debug things on your screen that we can't see.